# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - selecting specific element depending on the condition

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have HTML code like :

```
<div class="ex1">
    <div class="ex2">
        <span>test1</span>
        <span class="ex3">test2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ex2">
        <span>test3</span>
        <span class="ex3">test2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Selenium Webdriver.
And I need to create Java code which could:

If `<span>test3` then select a `<span class="ex3">` which located inside the same `div class="ex2"` 
But since I have div's and spans with the same className inside one main  I can't differ this spans..

Could you help me please with this issue?

So,something like this:

If `<span>test3 then <span class=ex3>test2.`
or
If `<span>test1 then <span class=ex3>test2.`

Thanks

Comment: Please mark either of the response(s) as answer which has helped you. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- Use this xpath to get to `<span>test1 then <span class=ex3>test2`:**

```
//span[.='test1']/following-sibling::span[.='test2']
```

And, use in code like this:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='test1']/following-sibling::span[.='test2']"));
```

**2-And, Use this xpath to get to `<span>test3 then <span class=ex3>test2`:**

```
//span[.='test3']/following-sibling::span[.='test2']
```

Use in code like this:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='test3']/following-sibling::span[.='test2']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the If statement as per your question in practice you can modify it as per your requirement.

```
WebElement test1_class1 =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ex1']//div[1]//span[1]")));  
String test1= test1_class1.getText();
WebElement test2_class1 =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ex1']//div[1]//span[2]")));
String test2_1 =test2_class1.getText();
WebElement test3_class2 =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ex1']//div[2]//span[1]")));
String test3 =test3_class2.getText();
WebElement test2_class2 =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ex1']//div[2]//span[2]")));
String test2_2 =test3_class2.getText();
try
{
if(test1.equals("test1"))
                    {
                    System.out.println(test2_1);
                    }
if(test3.equals("test3"))
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println(test2_2);
                    }

}
catch(Throwable e)
{
System.out.println("Exception in program"+e);
}
```